# numpy: How to reshape multiple 3-dimensional datacubes and 2-dimensional data labels into a single datacube and data label?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I reshape multiple 3-dimensional datacubes and 2-dimensional data labels into a single datacube and data label, in numpy?

Here is the iterate over the data set, my following code here please find it here -

```
# Example: Iterate over data set
for sample in dataset:
  datacube, labelmap = sample
  print(datacube.shape, labelmap.shape)
```

And the output looks like -

```
(389, 624, 23) (389, 624)
(389, 624, 23) (389, 624)
.
.
.
.
```

The question is how to reshape such a datacube which is 3 dimensions and a data label which is 2 dimensions in a single datacube and data label.

The two shapes would then have a size of (5 * 389 * 624, 15) for datacube and have a size of (5 * 389* 624) for label map.

Comment: Depends do you want it in numpy, pandas, or some other Python package? Should assume your input format was numpy? (If it was SQL(/HDFS), for some use-cases, keeping it in SQL(/HDFS) could be better than a bad Python implementation). And it also depends what you want to do with the result: aggregations, plotting, prediction, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datacube_stacked, labelmap_stacked = np.stack([datacube1,datacube2]) , np.stack([labelmap1, labelmap2])
```

Comment: @Mr.Technocrat I believe you want: `datacube, labelmap = np.stack([d for d, _ in dataset]) , np.stack([l for _, l in dataset])`

Comment: @user2246849 thank you so much! Yes, You are correct. I really wanted that one.